# How to use tensorflow.Estimator for reinforcement learning

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

The `tensorflow.Estimator` seems to gear toward supervised learning but seems to difficult to adopt for other task even if only small changes are needed for the model or training. For example, in reinforcement learning, I would need to feed a reward value which is not part of the `features`.

Comment: Having the same problem, would love to see how others are doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Estimators were meant for good-old supervised learning. So, adopting them to reinforcement learning will likely feel awkward. Here is an RL library that might be useful: https://github.com/tensorflow/agents.

Comment: I'm new to both Estimators and RL, could you please expand the answer to mention what differences make it awkward? As far as I can tell there is at least quite a bit of overlap: feature columns, session management, recording summaries for visualisation, saving checkpoints. The differences I think mostly have to do with labels and the fact that data is generated on the fly based on the interaction with the model. But I can't tell if I have the complete picture.

Comment: I have not trained RL models myself, so take the following with a grain of salt. If you want to use an estimator just to train a net inside your agent, it should be similar to regular supervised learning. You can feed generated on the fly data and labels with something like `https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator`